# Выполнение функции один раз для каждого элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, frontend

У меня есть несколько блоков с анимированными счетчиками (блоки с animated-block-1, animated-block-2, animated-block-3 и т. д.).

Задача в том, чтобы запускать счетчик **countNumbersSlider**
    один раз для каждого элемента при прокрутке и при наличии этого элемента в зоне видимости. Проблема появляется при скролле
    вверх-вниз. Счетчик перезапускается на каждый скролл вверх, не успев
    завершиться.

Я пробовал делать счетчики скроллов и флаги, но похоже, запутался.

Подскажите как правильно реализовать выполнение **countNumbersSlider** один раз для каждого элемента?

```
 $(window).on('wheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
        var wd = event.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;
        $('[id^="animated-block-"]').each(function () {
            if (document.querySelector('#' + this.id).getClientRects()[0].top < 300 && wd < 0) {
                countNumbersSlider('#' + this.id);
            }
        });
    });
```

**UPDATE**

Добавил фидл как в целом всё выглядит.
https://jsfiddle.net/vy652L3a/

Comment: Если хотите чтоб вам быстрее помогли, добавьте, пожалуйста, полный пример кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придумал решение https://jsfiddle.net/2pktvcua/

Создаем объекты, которые содержат селектор и флаг. Получаем массив объектов вида:

```
var projectCounter = [
     selector: 'animated-block-1', 
     isCalled: false
];
```

1. Проходимся по массиву.
2. Находим элемент по селектору.
3. Запускаем **countNumbersSlider**.
4. Ставим для **isCalled** значение **true**.

   ```
   $(window).on('wheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
       projectCounter.forEach(function (entry) {
           if (elementInView($('#' + entry.selector), false) && !entry.isCalled) {
               countNumbersSlider('#' + entry.selector);
               entry.isCalled = true;
           }
       })
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Я сделялЪ :), для маленького экрана плоховато работает функция, определяющая что элемент на экране, но суть вопроса не в этом...

```js
$(window).on('wheel', () => {
    $('[id^="animated-block-"]').each( function () {
        let el = $('#' + this.id);
        isScrolledIntoView(el) && countNumbersSlider(el);
    });
});

function countNumbersSlider(el) {
  if (el.attr('intervalId'))
    return;
    
  el.html(10)
  el.attr('intervalId', setInterval(count, 1000));
  
  function count() {
      let v = +el.html()-1;
      el.html(v);
      !v && clearInterval(el.attr('intervalId'));
      !v && el.attr('intervalId', null)
  }
}

function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + elem.height();
    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: wheat;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr><br><br>

<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<div id="animated-block-1"></div>

<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<div id="animated-block-2"></div>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<div id="animated-block-3"></div>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
<hr><br><br>
```